# Extracting Emails from Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

Thank you in advance!

I want to extract emails from Outlook. I'm a complete begginer

I tried this code which was already there but was not working properly, showing an Error code (438).

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtraerCorreos()

Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim ONameSpace As Object
Dim MyFolder As Object
Dim OItem As Object
Dim Fila As Integer

Dim Fecha As Date

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set ONameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MyFolder = ONameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Fila = 2

Fecha = "24/01/2023"

For Each OItem In MyFolder.Items

If Int(OItem.ReceivedTime) >= Fecha Then

        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 1).Value = OItem.SenderEmailAddress
        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 2).Value = OItem.Subject
        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 3).Value = OItem.ReceivedTime
        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 4).Value = OItem.Body
       
End If
   
        Fila = Fila + 1
   
Next OItem

Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Set ONameSpace = Nothing
Set MyFolder = Nothing


End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is this VBA running in an Excel module?

Comment: `For Each OItem In MyFolder.Items` not every `OItem` will necessarily be a mail item, so you should test for that before checking `OItem.ReceivedTime` and the other properties.  When you're getting an error it's useful to provide the error message (not just the number) and tell us which line has the error.

Comment: Which line of your code throws an error?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you are iterating over all items in the folder:

```
For Each OItem In MyFolder.Items

If Int(OItem.ReceivedTime) >= Fecha Then

        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 1).Value = OItem.SenderEmailAddress
        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 2).Value = OItem.Subject
        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 3).Value = OItem.ReceivedTime
        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 4).Value = OItem.Body
       
End If
```

Keep in mind that Outlook folders may contain different kind of items - *mails*, *appointments*, *notes* and etc. So, there is a high risk to use a property on an object which doesn't provide such property or method.

The error 438 occurs when you try to use a property or method that does not support by that object. as you know all objects have some properties and methods that you can use but there could be a situation when using a property or method that does not apply to a particular object.

So, I'd suggest checking the item type or message class (see the **MessageClass** property) before processing an item in the loop, so you could be sure such properties do exist, for example:

```
For Each OItem In MyFolder.Items

    If TypeName(OItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set oMail = oItem

        'do stuff with omail
    End If

Next
```

Also, instead of iterating over all items and checking the `ReceivedTime` property in the loop you can use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. They allow getting items that correspond to the search criteria, so you will iterate only through the items you need. Read more about these methods in the articles I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Answer (score 0):

You declared Fecha as a date but assigned Fecha= "24/01/2023" which is a string. Try Fecha = #24/01/2023# or Fecha = DateValue("24/01/2023")